# golang gin: router like django?

Tags: go

Can [gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) describe route like django?

In all examples, the routers are in one place, never found about attachment.

I would like to describe the routes in the package, and in the main file is simply to write something like.
example:

```
r := gin.New()
r.Include("/main", here_imported_route.Route)
```

## here_imported_route.go

```
package here_imported_route

Router := gin.New()
Router.Use(midl())
Router.Get("/test", hello)
```

and then on "/main/test" we get "hello".

Comment: why do you do that?What not satisfied with the way Gin?

Comment: I dont know Gin-way. I  want DRY. I have pkg auth and i want it use as route.Include(path, route_from_auth_pkg).

Comment: Unfortunately I do not understand what you need.

Comment: I wrote example, mb it help. https://github.com/FireGM/gin-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in main route like here

```
package main

import (
  "path_to_pkg/pkg"

  "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

var r *gin.Engine

func init() {
  r = gin.New()
  pkg.Concon(r.Group("/pkg"))

}

func main() {
  r.Run(":8080")
}
```

in imported package create concatenation func

pkg.go

```
package pkg

import "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

func Concon(g *gin.RouterGroup) {
  g.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.String(200, "pong")
  })
}
```

open 127.0.0.1:8080/pkg/ping and get "pong"

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you can accomplish this with route grouping. So you would have something like this:

```
r := gin.New()
main := r.Group("/main")
{
  main.GET("/test", hello)
}
```

See more details [here](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#grouping-routes).

Comment: No. I'm talk about portability. For write router in package and then do main route from package's route. Sorry for my bad english.